# jQuery - on link click --> toggle just the div found under link that triggered the event

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, javascript-framework

My application is programmatically generating some html code like this:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="class1">
<a href="#" class="my-link">some link text 1</a>
</div>
<div class="class2">
some content 1
</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
<div class="class1">
<a href="#" class="my-link">some link text 2</a>
</div>
<div class="class2">
some content 2
</div>
</div>
.........
over and over again
```

Using jQuery when I click on any link (inside the `<div class="class1">` ) I want to toggle just the `<div class="class2">` found under that link that triggered the event.

As you can see the class names repeat over and over again for every "container" div block.

Any idea how to accomplish this? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this.

```
$(".my-link").click(function(){
    $(this).closest("div").next(".class2").toggle();
});
```

Comment: This worked! Before this I've tried something like: $(this).closest(".class2").toggle(); and evidently didn't work. Just to learn something out of this, why by doing: $(this).closest("div").next(".class2").toggle(); works and:  $(this).closest(".class2").toggle();  doesn't? I appreciate your time!

Comment: @itgorilla - it's because `.closest` traverses up the dom tree, not down.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".my-link").click( function() {
  $(this).parents(".container").find(".class2").toggle();
})
```

or

```
$(".my-link").click( function() {
  $(this).parent().next(".class2").toggle();
})
```

Comment: +1. Alternatively `$(".class2", $(this).parents(".container")).toggle();`.

Comment: i like that one liner. +1 to you too sir

Answer (score 0):

The "next" jQuery selector returns the next sibling element.

```
$('.class1').click(function(e) {
  $(this).next().toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(function(){
 $(".my-link").click(function(){
  $(this).parent().next(".class2").toggle();
 });
});
```